# Need to get value for reference field instead of ID's

Tags: apex, controller

**Below is my code where I am describing all the fields of selected object. Instead of fetching ID for reference fields I need to fetch values for example I in case of account Id I want to fetch account name. I have all the reference fields stored in `lookUpFields` and I have a final list `finalRecordList`  which contains fields and values. So for reference fields I need them to be converted to values. Please help.**

```
@AuraEnabled
    Public static ListMapWrapper getMergeRecord (List<SObject> selecteData, String objectName){
        Map<string, List<dataWrapperClass>> wrapmap = new Map<string, List<dataWrapperClass>>();
        list<String> recordID = new list<String>();
        for(SObject record : selecteData){
            recordID.add(record.id);
        }
        
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>();
        List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>();
        List<String> lookUpFields = new List<String>();
        Schema.SObjectType convertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = convertType.getDescribe();    
        objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        system.debug('objectFields : '+objectFields);
        
        if(objectName == 'Account' || objectName == 'Opportunity' || objectName == 'Case'){
            for(String fieldName: objectFields.keySet()){
                string datatypeval = String.valueOf(r.fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType());
               // system.debug('datatypeval : '+datatypeval);
                if(datatypeval == 'REFERENCE' || datatypeval == 'reference'){
                    lookUpFields.add(objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getName());
                    system.debug('lookUpFields : '+lookUpFields);
                }
                if(fieldName != 'ShippingAddress' && fieldName != 'BillingAddress' && fieldName != 'Description' && fieldName != 'MasterRecordId' && fieldName != 'Jigsaw' ){
                       fieldNames.add(objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getName());
                   }
          
            } 
        }
        else if(objectName == 'Lead' || objectName == 'Contact'){
            for(String fieldName: objectFields.keySet()){
                string datatypeval = String.valueOf(r.fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType());
                if(datatypeval == 'REFERENCE' || datatypeval == 'reference'){
                    lookUpFields.add(objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getName());
                    system.debug('lookUpFields : '+lookUpFields);
                }
                if(fieldName != 'Name' && fieldName != 'ShippingAddress' && fieldName != 'BillingAddress' && fieldName != 'Description' && fieldName != 'MasterRecordId' && fieldName != 'Jigsaw'){
                       fieldNames.add(objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getName());
                   }
                
            } 
        }

        List<String> fieldlist = new List<String>();
        Set<String> aPINamesSet = objectFields.keyset();
        fieldlist.addAll(aPINamesSet);
        system.debug('fieldlist : '+fieldlist);
        
        string soqlQueryCurrent = string.join(fieldlist,',');
        
        if(soqlQueryCurrent.endsWithIgnoreCase(',')){
            soqlQueryCurrent = soqlQueryCurrent.removeEndIgnoreCase(',');                  
        }
        String queryStr ='SELECT '+soqlQueryCurrent+' FROM '+ObjectName+' where Id =:recordID';                
        List <Sobject> finalRecordList = Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(queryStr));
        system.debug('finalRecordList : '+finalRecordList);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert a Lookup field to a relationship and then get the Name for the related object you need to do something like:

```
objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getRelationshipName() + '.Name'
```

This will convert "AccountId" to "Account.Name", or "MyObject__c" to "MyObject__r.Name".